# Repeating Alarm gives notification inexact time

Tags: android, kotlin

I set repeating alarm set at 3:55AM. Suppose in the noon, at 1:00PM I on alarm button from app. Instantly i get notification for 3:55AM alarm. but why this?
Next day i get notification in exact time.

I convert alarm time in millis. 1st get a string in this formate
yyyyy/MM/dd" "HH:mm:ss... then convert it in millis by using localtime function. And set this millis time in am.setRepeating method.

```
     val d: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd")
        val currenttime: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
        val timeformate: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm")
        var time = timeformate.parse(singletime)

        //alarm_localtime
        val now: String = d.format(Date())
        //current_localtime
       // var currenttim = now + " " + currenttime.format(Date())
       // var current_local_time = localtime(currenttim)

        var alarmtime = (now + " " + singletime)
        var alarm_local_Time =  localtime(alarmtime)


        val notificationmassage = Intent(applicationContext, Notificationmassage::class.java)
        notificationmassage.putExtra("time", timeformate.format(time));

        val pendingintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            mContext,
            pos,
            notificationmassage,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )
        val am = mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        //Log.e("currenttime",Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis().toString() )
       // Log.e("alarmttime",alarm_local_Time.toString() )
        am.setRepeating(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            alarm_local_Time,
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
            pendingintent
        )




 @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    fun localtime(time: String): Long {
        var local_time =
            LocalDateTime.parse(time.replace(" ", "T").replace("/", "-"))
                .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                .toInstant()
                .toEpochMilli()
        return local_time
    }
```

Comment: can you confirm that alarm_local_Time is proper in millis ?

Comment: YES. I set same hour and minutes in calender like  cal[Calendar.HOUR] = 3 , cal[Calendar.MINUTE] = 55.. get same millis data.  And also next day alarm notification get at exact time at 3:55.

Comment: I am guessing that as you are setting it for current date and at 1:00PM for 3:55AM which is already passed , so it is firing that notification

Comment: try adding a day to your date  if the timestamp is older then current time

Comment: Thank you so much. i did it.    if (alarm_local_Time < current_local_time) {
            alarm_local_Time = alarm_local_Time + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

        }

Comment: It works perfectly now. Thank you @kelvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are setting it for current date and at 1:00PM for 3:55AM which is already passed , so it is firing that notification.
try adding a day to your date if the timestamp is older then current time.